# Seg fault javascript dialog Watir 3.0 and rautomation 0.7.2 ruby v 1.8.7

Tags: watir, rautomation

I'm trying to click ok in a javascript dialog in watir 3.0. I've simplified the code as best I can to this:

```
@ie.button(:id, "Associate Control Activity").click_no_wait

@ie.clickprompt

def clickprompt(btn="OK", txt="")
    sleep 1 until javascript_dialog.exists?
    #sleep 1 until javascript_dialog.button(btn).exists? #tried both
    javascript_dialog.button(btn).click
end
```

I often get this, some scripts more than others (very intermittent):

```
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:317: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [i386-mingw32]
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

OS is Win XP sp3. I call clickpompt often, some scripts use it repeatedly, but  it doesn't always fail the 4th time I call it, sometimes the 2nd, etc.  Do I need to do something differently?  Thanks

Comment: Might be related/same to https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/issues/31

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by faulty ffi gem. You need to install newer version of that gem for that problem to be solved. At least version 1.1.3 is needed.

The original issue can be seen here https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/213

Just execute the command:

```
gem install ffi
```

Or if you're using Bundler, then add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem "ffi", "~>1.1.3"
```

And execute:

```
bundle update ffi
```